# How can I add a 0-9 and a 0-99 hash to a List

Tags: c#

I have a variable that holds List

```
public class PhraseSource
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Romaji { get; set; }
    public string Kana { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add two additional fields so I have added these:

```
public int OneHash { get; set; }
public int TwoHash { get; set; }
```

- Where the value of OneHash is a hash that varies from 0-9 of the Id
- Where the value of TwoHash is a hash that varies from 0-99 of the Id

Can someone give me some suggestions of how I can populate these two columns?

Comment: What do you mean a hash that varies from 0-9 and 0-99 - what is the use of these fields?

Comment: Id.GetHashCode() % 10 jumps to mind.

Comment: @HansPassant - Your suggestion is I think what I am looking for. Is there a way that I can process all records of the list and do a one time set of the OneHash and TwoHash columns. It would just be needed one time as this List is only used to hold source data and once loaded it's never changed other than hopefully to add the hash information.

Comment: That just isn't necessary, just make the getter of the property smarter and return the result of the calculation.  You don't need a setter.

Comment: @HansPassant - your suggestion gives negative hashes.  For example: "4f2a7e28-4fbb-40ce-b4ad-006fe44423d8" gives -98 and -8  What I need is to get numbers between 0-9 and 0-99 only.  Thanks

Comment: Right, use Math.Abs(Id.GetHashCode()) % 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
public int OneHash => Math.Abs(Id.GetHashCode() % 10);
public int TwoHash => Math.Abs(Id.GetHashCode() % 100);
```

It takes the Hashcode of the Id string and returns the reminder of an division.

Comment: I think this is what I need but I need to add the values into these two fields after my list is created.  How can I apply this to every element in the list?

Comment: You do not need to add values to OneHash or TwoHash; these are "derived" by the Id. If the Id is set, then OneHash and TwoHash will be calculated at runtime if you access one of these properties. E.g.  if (phraseSource.OneHash == 9) will be handled at runtime as if (phraseSource.Id.GetHashCode() % 10 == 9)

Comment: thanks.  Just to confirm,  this will retrieve value of 0-9 and 0-99 only ?

Comment: I checked and some of the hashes are negative.  For example "4f2a7e28-4fbb-40ce-b4ad-006fe44423d8". gave a hash of -98

Comment: @Alan2 - oh, of course GetHashCode() may return negative numbers. I edited the answer (using Math.Abs)